# Change R.java file location

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

In Android Studio I noticed that **R.java** is generated in the same package as *package name* in  AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.companyname.app">

    ......

</manifest>
```

Is there a way to modify this behaviour ?
I want to have R.java placed in my main package *com.companyname.app* and Activity classes in *com.companyname.app.activity*. 
This way I can organize better my code.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="com.companyname.app.activity">

        ......

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please clarify the question

Comment: Why is it important?

Comment: I wouldn't use the words "organize better my code"..

Comment: I mean the Activity classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but what you can do is you can set applicationId in module.gradle .Gradle manifest merger modify packagename during build. Hope you can get desired result but setting proper package name in gradle applicationId.